# FFMPEG + Python - skipping unneeded frames on ffmpeg side

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to process a live hlsv stream, extract every 100th frame from it, and process it using openCV.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen([FFMPEG_BIN, "-i", src, 
                    "-loglevel", "quiet",
                    "-an", 
                    "-f", "image2pipe",
                    "-pix_fmt", "bgr24",
                    "-vcodec", "rawvideo", "-"],
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

while True:
    raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3)
    if frame_counter > 100:
        frame_counter = 0
        process_frame(raw_image)
    frame_counter += 1
```

Reading all the frames and dumping 99% of them seems inefficient, and has led me to pipe buffer issues (at least I suspect that).

Is it possible to skip the frames in FFMPEG, so that every 100th frame will go to the stdout?

Answer (score 1):

Use the select filter to keep every 100th frame.

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen([FFMPEG_BIN, "-i", src, 
                    "-loglevel", "quiet",
                    "-vf", "select=not(mod(n\,100))",
                    "-vsync", "0",
                    "-an", 
                    "-f", "image2pipe",
                    "-pix_fmt", "bgr24",
                    "-vcodec", "rawvideo", "-"],
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```